# Infinite Maclaurin Series Representation of Derivative of Power Series

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, power-series

Simple question but I'm getting lost along the way: Find the infinite series representation of

$$\frac{1}{(x-1)^3}$$

Looks suspiciously like power series; it can be rewritten as:
$$\frac{-1}{2}\cdot\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{1}{1-x}$$

How can this be translated to a power series now that $\frac{1}{1-x}$ has been isolated? From looking up the answer it is:

$$-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(n+1)(n+2)x^n}{2}$$

But it's unclear to me where $(n+1)(n+2)$ comes from. How are functions in the form $\frac{1}{(1-x)^n}$ solved?

Comment: Have you tried doing a term by term differentiation of the power series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ (i.e., $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^n},\quad|x|<1.$$
Now take the second derivative on both sides and you'll see where the $(n+1)(n+2)$ comes from (think about why you can take the derivative here). You can apply this technique to any function of the form $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^n}.$$